# Cannot run ATI R390 and i7 2600k HD3000 GPU together

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hdmi, gpu

[image]

I have both GPUs. But I have to disable the Intel HD Graphics 3000 because I'll only get a black screen when booting.

My monitor is connected to the R390 HDMI. However, I need both GPU's enabled, because I need HD3000 Quick Sync function for encoding purposes.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try a newer or different Radeon driver.

Comment: I didn, no go. Still getting black screens. It works just fine if I plug a 2nd monitor to the board HDMI, but that's not what I want, I just need my GPU to work with the single monitor I have.